# jwt token could not be parsed from the request in laravel 5 application

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, json-web-token

I am working on a token based authorization for my app. I am following -

```
https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-and-angularjs-token-based-auth-part1/
```

I've set up a different frontend folder and laravel serves as the backend.

The user is able to register and the credentials do get saved in the database but when i need to create a jwt token, I get an error :-

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException' with message '
The token could not be parsed from the request
```

RegisterController.php

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $newuser= $request->all();
    $password=Hash::make($request->input('password'));

    $newuser['password'] = $password;
    return Register::create($newuser);
}
}
```

LoginController.php

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

public function authenticate(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    try{
        if(! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    }
    catch(JWTException $e){
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}

public function getAuthenticatedUser(){

    try{
        if(! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()){
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }
    }
    catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e){
        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }
    catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e){
        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }
    catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e){
        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }

    return response()->json(compact('user'));
}
```

}

routes.php

```
Route::post('/api/register', 'RegisterController@register');
Route::post('api/authenticate', 'LoginController@authenticate');
Route::get('api/authenticate/user', 'LoginController@getAuthenticatedUser');
```

I don't see any issues, it should work just fine but don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Try to use this https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt, I think is more simple and customizable

Comment: Did you delete the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware?

Comment: @pespantelis - I commented it in kernal.php - /*\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,*/

Comment: In what route is the error?

Comment: @Hicask - api/authenticate/user

Comment: @Hicask - i didn't get u..

Comment: Are u sure that the token is correct??

Comment: How do I check that? i used postman but it gives the same message - "The token could not be parsed from the request"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by updating my .htaccess file to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just did . Thanks :-)